# /usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so: could not read symbols: File in wrong format

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, cross-compiling, compiler-warnings

I try to cross compile `bluez-utils-3.36` from the sources.

**Host machine (machine where i build the code)**

```
Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2420 0 @ 1.90GHz
OS Version: Linux 2.6.32-44 generic
```

**Target machine: (the target on which the compiled file should run)**

```
Processor: ARM926EJ-S rev 5 (v5l)
OS Version: Linux 2.6.35.3-571
```

The target seems to have an ARM processor, so i navigated to `bluez-utils-3.36` and executed the following command:

```
./configure \
--host=arm-linux \
BLUEZ_CFLAGS=-I/home/shortened_the_path/bluetooth/bluez-libs-3.36/include \
BLUEZ_LIBS="-L/home/shortened_the_path/bluetooth/bluez-libs-3.36/src/.libs -lbluetooth"
```

This run successfully. After this i executed `make`, and get this error:

`/usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so: could not read symbols: File in wrong format`

- Is my libgmodule-2.0.so file corrupt?

Does anyone know how i can possibly solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You are compiling for arm but the libgmodule library which you are trying to link against is built for your PC architecture. So you have to cross compile glib which is a dependency of bluez.

Look at this link which explains in detail how to cross compile bluez

http://wiki.beyondlogic.org/index.php?title=Cross_Compiling_BlueZ_Bluetooth_tools_for_ARM

Comment: Do i also have to install glib with `make install` after i cross compiled it?

Comment: tell me what is your need . make is involved in cross compilation also. so what do you mean by using it with make

Comment: You can cross compile bluez-utils similar to other packages

Comment: Then you have not looked carefully. Bluez is a package only.

Comment: I followed your guide, and it helped me solving the error with `libgmodule-2.0.so` but now there is another error: `bluez-libs-3.36/src/.libs/libbluetooth.so: could not read symbols: File in wrong format`

Comment: Did you cross compile bluez-libs properly

Comment: aw man this is so confusing... yes i cross-compiled it with no errors. But i noticed that i compiled it with `gcc`instead with my toolchain. Even though i replaced `CC` in my makefile with `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc`... so i configured it this time like this `CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc ./configure` and now i get the `libgmodule-2.0.so`error again.

Comment: In the README i found this: `In order to compile Bluetooth utilities you need following software packages:
 - Linux Bluetooth protocol stack (BlueZ)` So do i need to install BlueZ before compiling `bluez-libs` and `bluez-utils`?!

Comment: ok i will list the packages you need to cross compile 1)zlib 2)libffi 3)glib 4)expat 5)dbus 6)libical 7)ncurses 8)readline 9)bluez then whatever you need

Comment: Ok, so there is no other way, then installing these packages? Is it possible to not install them, but just link at them somehow?

Comment: OK, thank you very much for your help! i will try it tomorrow and report.

Comment: My sysadmin told me that it is possible without installing these packages, i just have to compile them and link them, i am not allowed to install anything on this machine. But thx for your try to help.